# Magento 2.2: (API) set UserContext user type to customer during token creation

Tags: magento2.2, cart, api, login

I've been struggling with the following scenario: i have a custom API endpoint to process the guest to customer login. This endpoint basically does the same thing as `/integration/customer/token` with one exception. During the authentication it merges any products the visitor had as a guest into the customer cart of the account they are logging in to.

Problem is that any which way i try, i keep running into the same error: `"Invalid state change requested"` when i try to save the updated customer quote.

Some investigation led me to the class `\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Plugin\AccessChangeQuoteControl` in the Magento_Quote module. This class is a plugin that is triggered before the `save()` method of the QuoteRepository. Turns out that as a guest you are not allowed to save a quote that has customer id. And during the authentication procedure you apparently are still a guest, even after authenticating.

Is there any way to make the backend system aware of the fact that the customer is logged in properly without having to do a second API call that contains the Authorization header with the new token? Somehow i have to make sure `$this->userContext->getUserType()` in the `AccessChangeQuoteControl` plugin returns `UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER` in stead of `UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_GUEST` but i have no clue on how to make this happen.

Thanks!

Comment: UserContextInterface will give you customer id and it will work.

Comment: Well, that's the whole thing. I'd expect it to return a customer id as the authentication process is done just before. Unfortunately the UserContext will still return a guest type an no customer id

Comment: Actually i faced the same issue and but when i pass Auth of customer token i am getting customer token.

Comment: Have you tried the solution ?

Comment: Other priorities in this project atm, what else is new. I don't think this solution doesn't fit my case exactly but i think it has everything i need in order to get things going. I will let you know (and update my answer) as soon as i've been able to tinker around with it. Either way, already thanks for your extended answer!

Answer (score 1):

Magento gets the customer data with passing anything except **token value** in **API** call.

In between magento calls some API related controllers for the same

> vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/webapi.xml

```
<route url="/V1/customers/me" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface" method="getById"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self"/>
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
        </data>
 </route>
```

**in this API call magento get customer data based on token.**

Based on API url `url="/V1/customers/me"` magento calls function from

Magento calls In-between call of dispatch function.

> vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php

```
 public function dispatch(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
 {
     /** In between code **/
     // In the same file
     $this->processApiRequest();

 }
 protected function processApiRequest()
 {
      $inputParams = $this->getInputParamsResolver()->resolve();
 }
```

**And this `resolve()` function calls `override()` function**

> vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php

```
 public function resolve()
 {
      $inputData = $this->paramsOverrider->override($inputData, $route->getParameters());
 }
```

and `overide()` function calls `getOverriddenValue()` function

> vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/ParamsOverrider.php

```
 public function override(array $inputData, array $parameters)
 {
      $value = $this->paramOverriders[$paramValue]->getOverriddenValue();
 }
```

`getOverriddenValue()` calls `ParamOverriderInterface`

> vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/Rest/Request/ParamOverriderInterface.php

- To Override parameter values
- Parameters in the webapi.xml can be forced. This ensures that on
  specific routes, a specific value is always used.
- For instance, if there is a `".../me/..."` route, the route should use
  only user information specific to the
- currently logged in user. More specifically, if there was a
  `"/customers/me/addresses"` route, the service method
- invoked could have a signature of `"getAddresses($customerId)"`, but in
  the `webapi.xml`, the $customerId parameter
- **would be forced to be the customer id of the current authenticated
  user.**
- **The forced override parameter configuration is in the webapi.**

---

```
   <data>
     <parameter name="customer.id" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
   </data>
```

and for business logic of this function is in file -

> vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/ParamOverriderCustomerId.php

```
   /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
   public function getOverriddenValue()
   {
       if ($this->userContext->getUserType() === UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER) {
           return $this->userContext->getUserId();
   }
   return null;
   }
```

**So this is how Magento get Customer Id between API calls !!**

**solution 1**

```
public function __construct(
   \Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface $userContext
){
   $this->userContext = $userContext;
}

$customerId = $this->userContext->getUserId();
```

---

**solution 2**

```
$ch = curl_init('dev.magento2.com/rest/V1/customers/me');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($result);
echo $json->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got similar problem. Also i tried make order programatically by soap for particular user but not logged in. It ends up with situation as you describe above. I was trying few aproaches, but nothing works as i expected. So finally i overwrite class which leads to exception: \Magento\Quote\Model\ChangeQuoteControl by di

```xml
<preference for="\Magento\Quote\Model\ChangeQuoteControl" type="ChangeQuoteControl" />
```

```
class ChangeQuoteControl extends \Magento\Quote\Model\ChangeQuoteControl
{
    protected $forceIsAllowed = false;
    
    public function forceIsAllowed($forceIsAllowed){
        $this->forceIsAllowed = $forceIsAllowed;
        
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function isAllowed(CartInterface $quote): bool
    {    
        if($this->forceIsAllowed){
            return true;
        } else {
            return parent::isAllowed($quote);
        }
    }
    
}
```

And before i place order:

```php
$this->changeQueoteControll->forceIsAllowed(true);
```

I dont like it, but it works fine, i was able to place order for particular not logged in customer.